# How can I shorten this vector without having to type in every single element?

Tags: r

how can I shorten this vector without having to type every single one of the elements? I want to use these as labels on a barplot, but I am finding the code so long. Is there any simple and shorter way? Thanks
I tried `paste("1", letters[1:6], sep = "")` but falling short as you can see and I don't know how to lengthen it.

```
c("1a", "1b", "1c", "1d", "1e", "1f", "2a" ,"2b", "2c"  , "2d", "2e", "2f", "3a", "3b", "3c", "3d", "3e", "3f", "3g", "4a", "4b", "4c", "4d" , "4e", "4f", "4g", "5a", "5b", "5c", "5d")
```

Comment: Hey guys. Very thankful for the help. The numbers in my vector are not equal though. Using the input from here, this is the furthest I could come to modify the code. But the letters are not agreeing with the numbers. Remember that these are labels for a simple barplot, so they have to be the right number/letters: paste0(rep(1:5, times=c(6,6,7,7,4)), rep(letters[1:5], 5))

Answer (score 2):

For variable lenght of letters you can do

```
l_len <- c(6, 6, 7, 7, 4)
num <- rep(seq_along(l_len), l_len)
let <- unlist(lapply(l_len, function(i) letters[seq_len(i)]))

paste0(num, let)
# [1] "1a" "1b" "1c" "1d" "1e" "1f" "2a" "2b" "2c" "2d" "2e" "2f" "3a" "3b" "3c" "3d" "3e" "3f" "3g" "4a" "4b" "4c" "4d" "4e" "4f" "4g" "5a" "5b" "5c" "5d"
```

For a fixed length of numbers and letters you can use:

```
paste0(rep(1:5, each = 6), letters[1:6])
# [1] "1a" "1b" "1c" "1d" "1e" "1f" "2a" "2b" "2c" "2d" "2e" "2f" "3a" "3b" "3c" "3d" "3e" "3f" "4a" "4b" "4c" "4d" "4e" "4f" "5a" "5b" "5c" "5d" "5e" "5f"
```

`paste0` is short for `paste(..., sep = "")`, `rep` repeats the argument `1:5` 6 times each, `letters[1:6]` is repeated automatically so that the length matches the length of `rep(1:5, each = 6)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way using `outer`

```
fun <- function(x, y) paste0(x, y)
c(t(outer(1:5, letters[1:6], Vectorize(fun))))
#[1] "1a" "1b" "1c" "1d" "1e" "1f" "2a" "2b" "2c" "2d" "2e" "2f" "3a" "3b" .....
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rep` and `sequence` to produce the desired vector:

```
x  <- c(6,6,7,7,4)
paste0(rep(seq_along(x), x), letters[sequence(x)])
# [1] "1a" "1b" "1c" "1d" "1e" "1f" "2a" "2b" "2c" "2d" "2e" "2f" "3a" "3b" "3c"
#[16] "3d" "3e" "3f" "3g" "4a" "4b" "4c" "4d" "4e" "4f" "4g" "5a" "5b" "5c" "5d"
```

Comment: Thanks for this code! It worked like a charm...I am soo glad. Thanks @GKi! :)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative avoiding `letters`, what about making use of decimal to hexadecimal conversion?

```
unlist(Map(function(i) sprintf("%x", 16 * i + 10:15), 1:5))
#[1] "1a" "1b" "1c" "1d" "1e" "1f" "2a" "2b" "2c" "2d" "2e" "2f" "3a" "3b" "3c"
#[16] "3d" "3e" "3f" "4a" "4b" "4c" "4d" "4e" "4f" "5a" "5b" "5c" "5d" "5e" "5f"
```

The flag `"%x"` prints a decimal integer as a hexadecimal integer; the set of elements corresponds to the numbers `16 * i + 10`, `16 * i + 11`, ..., `16 * i + 15` for `i` from 1 to 4.